# QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, querydsl

I get this exception **from time to time** in the production environment and have not been able to reproduce it locally. Others had this problem, but it happened when either updating or deleting.

I have a listener class mapped to the Tag class which on prePersist(), makes sure that a user does not have saved more than x tags.

The Tag class is:

```
    @Entity
    @EntityListeners({ TagListener.class })
    public class Tag extends AbstractEntity {

    ...
    }
```

The TagService class saves tag objects.

```
@Service
public class TagService extends AbstractService<Tag> {

public Tag saveTagForUser(AbstractEntity entity, User user) {
...
return save(tag);       

}
```

> The TagListener listens when tag objects are saved and deletes some of
>   them if that is necessary.

```
@Component
public class TagListener {

    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;

    /**
     * Autowires this component's bean injections.
     */
    private void autowire() {
        if (tagService == null) {
            ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
        }
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Tag tag) {
        autowire();
        if (tagService.listUserTags(tag.getUser()).size() > Constants.Tags.maxPerUser) {
            tagService.deleteAllUserTagsNotInTopN(tag.getUser(), Constants.Tag.maxPerUser);
        }
    }
}
```

> Note that the exception is thrown on listUserTags, and NOT on
>   deleteAllUserTagsNotInTopN

```
**javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1**
    at **org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1800)**
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1705)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at **com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:197)**
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:414)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:399)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    **at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at ro.app.service.tag.TagService.listUserTags(TagService.java:823)
    at ro.app.listener.TagListener.prePersist(TagListener.java:47)**
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.preCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor173.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:42)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:414)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:399)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.save(Unknown Source)
    at ro.app.service.AbstractService.save(AbstractService.java:530)
    **at ro.app.service.TagService.saveTagForUser(TagService.java:351)**
```

Saving the tag objects is done inside a transaction.
Any clues what the problem might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was because of deleting tags (done in the deleteAllUserTagsNotInTopN() method), although it was not visible in the stacktrace. In the TagRepository, I replaced the **delete** method with **deleteInBatch** method:

```
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag,Long> {

     void deleteInBatch(Iterable<Notification> notifications);
}
```